# Estimate loss of information due to a low rank approximization by SVD

Tags: spectral-theory, svd

I have a matrix $X$ and I compute its Singular Value Decomposition:
$$X = U \Sigma V^T$$
then, I take the lower rank approximization:
$$X_k = U_k \Sigma_k V^T_k$$
where $k < rank(X)$, $U_k$ is made of the first $k$ columns of $U$, $\Sigma_k$ is the $k \times k$ diagonal matrix whose elements are the first $k$ singualar values of $X$ and $V_k$ is composed of the first $k$ columns of the $V$ matrix.

I would like to know how to estimante the information loss due to the lower rank approximization.

Is that possible to compute it?

Thanks

Comment: How do you quantify information?

Comment: I would say entropy. But any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to see that $||X-X_k||_F^2=||\Sigma-\Sigma_k||_F^2$, where $||A||_F^2$ is the square of the Frobenius norm, i.e. the sum of squares of the individual matrix elements of $A$. We have $X_k=U_k\Sigma_k V_k^T=U\Sigma_k V^T$. Because $U^T$ and $V$ are orthogonal matrices, they preserve the euclidean norm of the individual row and column vectors, so that we have $||X-X_k||_F^2=||U^T(X-X_k)||_F^2=||(U^T(X-X_k))V||_F^2$ and $(U^T(X-X_k))V=\Sigma-\Sigma_k$. A similar argument proves $||X-X_k||_2=||\Sigma-\Sigma_k||_2$, where $||A||_2$ is the spectral norm of $A$, i.e. the [operator norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) induced by the Euclidean norm.

- $||\Sigma-\Sigma_k||_F^2$ is just the sum of squares of the omitted singular values.
- $||\Sigma-\Sigma_k||_2$ is the spectral norm of $X-X_k$. It is given by the largest omitted singular value.

The Frobenius norm can be interpreted to measures the energy of the omitted information.

Comment: Is not square of Frobenius norm be better represented as  $||A||_F^2$, instead of  $||A||_2^2$ ? As,  $||A||_2^2$ is normally reserved for 2nd norm.